# Foreign key to each table or iterate through tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

How would be best practice, or how is more optimal to get data from different tables in this case?

- Table Agents

  - id
  - company_id
  - name
- Table Properties

  - id
  - added_by (agent)
- Table Transactions

  - id
  - property_id

To get all the properties for company ID 5000 I can:

- add a company_id column to properties and transactions and then I make this query:

  ```
  $properties = Property::where('company_id', 5000)->get();
  $transactions= Transaction::where('company_id', 5000)->get();
  ```

OR SQL

```
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE company_id = 5000;
```

- iterate through tables and get the data:

  ```
  $properties = Property::whereHas('agent', function($query){
      $query->where('company_id', 5000);
  })->get();

  $transactions = Transaction::whereHas('property', function($query){
      $query->whereHas('agent', function($q){
          $q->where('company_id', 5000);
      });
  })->get();
  ```

OR SQL

```
SELECT * FROM transactions T 

LEFT JOIN properties P ON T.property_id = P.id

LEFT JOIN users U ON P.added_by = U.id

WHERE U.company_id = 5000;
```

In my example I used PHP and Eloquent ORM but the example can be as well as pure MYSQL or any other language. Thank you.

Update:

Here is the SQL for create.

http://pastebin.com/65ry7BeY

Comment: why two queries? one single `JOIN` query can trivially get that information. join agent->properties on agent.id=added_by

Comment: And for transactions? If I need all transactions for a company?

Comment: `SELECT transaction.id from transactions t join properties p on t.property_id = p.id where p.company_id = :company`

Comment: Your solution means to add a company_id to properties. Is this necessary if I already have this column on agents?

Comment: Iteration is never necessary with a relational representation of data. Suggest you read about the basics of relational databases and querying in SQL.

Comment: A single `SELECT` with multiple tables being `JOINed` is _usually_ the "best" way.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the competing `SELECTs`.  Most of use know MySQL, but don't know the many, many, ORMs, CMSs, etc, that obfuscate the SQL.

Comment: I added the SQL queries and the CREATE code in a pastebin link. Please check.